# Ternary Operator is not working, can I put (this or that) as the expression?

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I'm having trouble finding why this doesn't work:

```
value = ( (value == undefined) || (typeof(value) !=== "number") ) ? 1 : value;
```

From what I understand this should set `value` to either `1` or `value`(variable), depending on whether or not `value` is not a number.

If value is not a number, change it to `1`, if it is, keep it.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `!===` should be `!==`: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token =`. **But** you will still get an error if you `value` was not declared... just doing `value = typeof(value) !== "number" ? 1 : value` should be fine (since `undefined` is not a number either).

Comment: Could you specify "doesn't work"? What happens when you run the code, and how does that differ from what you expect? Do you get any error message?

Comment: For the future, you will generally get better advice if you provide a better description of the problem than "doesn't work".

Comment: @FelixKling that worked! thank you, i overlooked that! Another SO question suggested using === but when i negated it i forgot to remove one = sign. Thanks!!

Comment: And thank you to everyone else who was able to catch my error.

Comment: Minor nit, `value == undefined` is dangerous because you can reassign undefined. Try something like `typeof value === 'undefined'` instead to be more safe.

Comment: @tjameson Or `value == (function(){})()`

Comment: @Asad - If we're golfing: `value == void 0`

Comment: @tjameson: You cannot reassign `undefined` in ES5 anymore. At least in the latest browser, you don't have a problem with it. In the worst case, just compare against `null`: `value == null`, it's the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick look:

!=== (with three equal signs) is a typo.  The correct operator is !== (with two equal signs).

Whenever you have Javascript problems, I strongly urge working through all warnings and problems at http://www.jslint.com/ --it helps catch a lot of stuff the eye doesn't see easily.

Comment: THANK YOU. that site is amazing and will help me so much!

Answer (score 2):

This works just fine if you change `!===` (which doesn't actually exist) to `!==` (which is the logical inverse of `===`).

Answer (score 2):

You were using one too many equals signs. The correct syntax is `!==`.

Just use `value = (typeof(value) !== "number") ? 1 : value;`

The `(value == undefined)` condition is redundant, because the latter is always true when the former is.

Comment: Thank you Asad! Very true, I'll remove that.